# How to run process in administrative mode from Emacs?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, root

I've been using `powershell.el` in MS Windows Emacs, but I sometimes want
to be administrative mode so that I can do software installation via
chocolatey, etc.

Is there any way to call `shell` command, or `call-process`, in admin.
mode from Emacs?

Comment: I don't think this is possible from within emacs, but you could try to elevate the privileges with the script described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/).

Comment: I am also stuck with pretty much the same problem. I don't understand why I find working with Windows OS so difficult.